# OrientDB POJO Method proxy not working properly

Tags: proxy, pojo, orientdb

I am using the OObjectDatabaseTx implementation of OrientDB to store my POJOs in the database. When I try to retrieve some POJOs with a SQL commant, I get the result set but the attributes of the POJOs seem to be empty (getters regurning null).

I register my classes properly with

```
db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(MyUser.class);
```

The following code describes my problem:

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("name", username);
    List<MyUser> users = db.command(
            new OSQLSynchQuery<MyUser>(
                  "select * from MyUser where "
                + "name = :name"))
                .execute(params);
    for (MyUser founduser : users) {

        ODocument doc = db.getRecordByUserObject(founduser, false);
        String pass = doc.field("pwd");

        assertEquals(pass != null, true); // passes
        assertEquals(founduser.getPwd() != null, true); // fails
    }
```

How can I get the method getPwd to return the proper value?

I am now using Version 1.3.0 and this has worked before (afaik in 1.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if the POJO has the "pwd" field set inside of it?

Comment: When I stepped through in my debugger, it had all its fields set to null. But it had the method proxy attached to it.

Comment: Do you have a hint how I could find out what the problem is?

Comment: Try with a reload() of the object.

Comment: I tried founduser = db.reload(founduser) but it did not help. Is there any other thing I could try?